# Convert a date time character string to date - YYYYMM format

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a character string date time string but need to convert the same into `YYYYMM` date format. Cannot seem to find a solution as all functions are converting into `NA` or weird date format.

```r
Date_format_current <- '02/09/2020 23:35'
```

Comment: using strptime is converting some of them into character some of them into NA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

current <- '02/09/2020 23:35'

as.yearmon(dmy_hm(current))
#> [1] "Sep 2020"
#Or
format(dmy_hm(current), "%Y-%m")
#> [1] "2020-09"
#Or
format_ISO8601(dmy_hm(current), precision = "ym")
#> [1] "2020-09"
```

Comment: With only base R: `format(as.Date(current, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y%m")` or swap the %d and %m in `"%m/%d/%Y"` if that is the order.